# How to get apache serve gzip files?

Tags: php, angular, apache

Front end: Angular
Back end: PHP
Server: Apache

1. Compress files with webpack plugin (bundle.js.gz)
2. Run but I get errors.
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token   bundle.js.gz:1
3. Status code is 200 and Headers looks like

   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

What do I miss?

Comment: How are you loading the bundle.js at runtime?

Comment: With command (npm run build:prod), generate bundle.js.gz under dist directory.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is serve pre-compressed content. (bundle.js.gz)
Add the following part to your site.conf and reload.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files if they exist
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.(css|js)"         "$1\.$2\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule "\.css\.gz$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$"  "-" [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header append Content-Encoding gzip

      # Force proxies to cache gzipped &
      # non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.
apache serves the file with the proper content-type and the proper filename (no .gz) but compressed.